# multiple annotation have issue to get selected index annotation

Tags: iphone, objective-c, mkannotationview

I have displayed multiple annotation successfully in mapView in my iphone application, but I have problem too .. In top of the screen I have two Tab Map and List . map display all annotation in map and list display those data in Tableview which is display in map. when I click on particular cell i get all the particular detail of that cell.but when I try to get id from Tap annotation my array getting lots of id after comparison of name because we have same name in my array list so how can I differentiate from annotation tag. How to set tag of annotations ?

Comment: Please show the code where you "try to get id from tapped annotation".  Are you detecting tap in didSelectAnnotationView or the callout accessory?  Have you defined a custom annotation object?

Comment: i am using calloutAccessoryControlTapped method for Tap on annotation.

Comment: from annotation.title i get proper id of that annotation , but when my array have same Name than i compared i get multiple index for that annotation and i dont get perticular detail of that annotation

Comment: In that delegate method, doesn't `view.annotation` give you the annotation that was tapped?

Comment: View.annotation gives me <TagMark: 0x638d870> types of responce .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `calloutAccessoryControlTapped` delegate method, use `view.annotation` to access the annotation that was tapped.

If you have a custom annotation class, you can cast it to easily access the properties (you may also want to first check if the annotation tapped is an instance of the class you're interested in--important if you're using multiple annotation classes):

```
if ([view.annotation isKindOfClass:[TagMark class]]) {
    TagMark *tm = (TagMark *)view.annotation;
    NSLog(@"tm.someProperty = %@", tm.someProperty);
}
```