# Storyboard, Pass detailed information to UITableView from mapView callout

Tags: android, uitableview, storyboard, android-mapview

I have annotations on a map. I have a detaildisclosure button on annotation callouts that brings up a UITableView for further details about that location (phone, address, directions, etc).

I am unable to find a good example or tutorial that acknowledges the table cells I have created and labeled in the storyboard. Additionally, many tutorials use a dictionary as a data source. I think this is a bit overkill, isn't it? I have the information in an array for the annotation already, how can I pass this to the next view being pushed onto the navigation controller?

I only have a label and three cells that need to be populated (have their text changed). I finally managed to see the cells I created in the storyboard by commenting out the numberOfSectionsInTable and numberOfRowsInSection.

What is the easiest way to do this?

Also, I created IBActions for the three labels, but I can't control+click to connect them to the cells. I'll need data from the annotation array to make the buttons to call the phone number, etc.

Do I put it somewhere in my mapView controller, in the controlTapped method?

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView annotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view calloutAccessoryControlTapped:(UIControl *)control {

    //this determines what kind of item was selected
    if ([control isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]]) {

        NSLog(@"Trying to load VenueIdentifier...");

        FinderViewController *fvi = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"VenueIdentifier"];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:fvi animated:YES];

    }
}
```

Comment: Are you asking how to retrieve details of the annotation whose callout was tapped in the calloutAccessoryControlTapped method?  Are you using a custom annotation class?  These might help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7449263/467105, http://stackoverflow.com/a/7432040/467105

Comment: @AnnaKarenina Thanks, I am using a custom annotation class. OK, so I setup the details with something like this, right?


MapViewAnnotation *annotationTapped = (MapViewAnnotation *)view.annotation;


Once I'm in the next view, how do I call things that arein this *annotationTapped and set them as table cell values?

Comment: To pass annotationTapped to FinderViewController, you can add it as a property in that vc and set it before doing the push.  Then in FVC, access the properties of annotationTapped.  Regarding how to put them in cell values, generally you do that in cellForRowAtIndexPath based on what the indexPath is.  I haven't used storyboarding yet so can't give specific answer but suggest you look at [WWDC 2011 Session 309 - Introducing Interface Builder Storyboarding](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2011/) (must be a registered developer).  The session covers prototyped and static table views.